# Auto update reports generated in report studio, when new rows are added in database

Tags: automation, db2, report, auto-update, cognos-10

I am using Cognos 10. I have created a model in FM using some tables in DB2. Then I have created a package and published it. I have also generated reports on this in report studio. Everything went well and the report looks fine.

Now the actual problem is, I added some rows to the tables which I used for this project and the previous report is not updating. I tried refreshing data source in FM but it didn't update. So I had to create a new model and publish a package and generate a new report each time I add data to my DB2 tables.

I have seen Tableau reports being auto-update when database changes occurs. Is this possible with Cognos?

Is there any other way in which I can just do something in report studio and the report automatically updates to the new data present in DB2 tables?? So that I don't have to create a new model,package and report for each DB2 insert??

Comment: I just realized you are talking about rows and not columns. I've deleted my answer which does not apply. As for rows you should not have to do anything. Any new rows added to a table should automatically be added to the result set, assuming they are not filtered out. Check for date range or other filters that could be restricting your results.

Comment: Even if the rows are automatically updated to the query subject, I still have to publish the package right??    And is there any way that I can see the data of the query subject in Framework Manager itself?

Comment: You should only have to publish the package when you make some sort of change to the model. Simply adding rows to a table should not require a republish. To see the data for a query subject in Framework Manager click on the Test tab.

Comment: I have added some rows to my table. I used Test tab to view the data, its updated in Framework manager. I opened a previously generated report of that package(validated the report), and clicked on "view tabular data", the rows are not updated here.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. There is something missing here. The only thing I can thing of some sort of caching of report results.

Comment: Actually now the reports are updated with new data entries. But the problem is some reports are not updated while the others did, which are of the same package. For example, I have generated 6 reports using that package. But when I have added new rows to the Query subject, only 4 reports are updated and the rest two are not updated. The updation is also taking time like 10 to 15min but not happening instantly .... why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue here if I use a Framework Manager model. The only solution that I found right now is to write SQL directly in Report Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem with local cache.  I had this issue before.  The new data row was not shown in Report after insert.  I needed to disable local cache in the Framework to make it work.